# add currency format in janus gridex columns

Tags: c#, janus, gridex

in my project, for seeing product list by using F10, a form has built in runtime and for decimal columns, it add currency name in behind of text, i don't want it. which property is it?

Comment: Please share us a [maninal reporducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you already have.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the FormatMode and FormatString properties for the grid column.

A format string of "C2" will give you currency with 2 decimal places.
A format string of "N2" will give you a simple 2 digit decimal number,